# How do I find the fourth order transfer function from this step response diagram?

Tags: transfer-function

I have the following diagram of a system's step response:

[image]

I'm having trouble understanding how to calculate the system's transfer function for fourth order.
hir: [How do I find the second order transfer function from this step response diagram?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/117124/how-do-i-find-the-second-order-transfer-function-from-this-step-response-diagram)
I have learned how to do it for the second but I do not know how to calculate this for the fourth order.

[image]

Comment: Manually do it using a simulator to mimic the response. A bit fiddly of course but, that's what you get with 4th order filters.

Comment: Thanks. I did it with matlab and i got it. i want to know is there any method to calculate it like 2. order?

Comment: You can probably find \$ \omega_n \$ from the oscillations on that output, but being able to determine \$p_1,p_2,\xi\$ will not be as easy. If you have that data, I would suggest using some ARMA toolbox to identify such 4th order model.

Comment: Do you have Matlab's system identification toolbox?

Comment: I can make an active filter look like that on an interactive simulator, but why bother?