# How to calculate natural frequency and zeta of underdamped, 2nd order system if only given experimental data?

Tags: frequency, step-response

How do I estimate the values of \$K\$, \$\zeta\$ and natural frequency, given the plot of unit step response of the system in time domain?
I figured that at \$t = \infty\$, \$Y(t) = K\$ and I calculate that. How do I go about calculating
the \$\zeta\$ and \$\omega\$ from the graph?

Comment: Show the graph of the step response.

Comment: Its just like the normal graph of a underdamped system.
Kinda like this : https://apmonitor.com/pdc/uploads/Main/2nd_order_exercise_1c.png

Comment: @averagemathguy69 It wouldn't hurt to give more details if you want a good response. I doubt you'd want a "kinda like this" answer. Otherwise, this seems like a [duplicate](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/117141/95619).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Thanks a lot! This is my first time posting here and I am sorry about not posting the details, I'll keep that in mind from now! I got my answer from the link you had posted, this helped A LOT. Thanks again.

Comment: @averagemathguy69 Then maybe the moderators can mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find the second order transfer function from this step response diagram?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/117124/how-do-i-find-the-second-order-transfer-function-from-this-step-response-diagram)